# Open a word doc from excel and copy needed information to excel file

Tags: vba, excel

I have several word files. They are build like this
text
text
text
Name: Mick
Date: 1-1-1
text
text
Item: Item11      material: Gold
text
text

I am building a macro that can open a word file, put the name in Cell A1 and put the item in Cell A2. I have found a code on internet and adjusted it a little. The following code makes a selection from the beginning of the word doc until a word is found and copies that selection in a given cell.

I hope someone can show me how i can adjust this so the selection begins right before the needed value an stops after it

code below is for item:

```
Dim wdApp As Object, wdDoc As Object, wdRng As Object

Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
With wdApp
  .Visible = True
    Set wdDoc = .Documents.Open("path", False, True, False)
    With wdDoc
      Set wdRng = .Range(0, 0)
      With .Range
        With .Find
          .Text = "material"
          .Forward = True
          .MatchWholeWord = True
          .MatchCase = True
          .Execute
        End With
        If .Find.found = True Then
          wdRng.End = .Duplicate.Start
          Sheets("sheet1").Range("A2").value = wdRng
        End If
  End With
      .Close False
    End With
  .Quit
End With
Set wdRng = Nothing: Set wdDoc = Nothing: Set wdApp = Nothing
```

Anyone any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the procedure below. It will open the specified Word document, parse the required values via Regular Expressions, place those values into cells `A1` and `A2`, and then close the Word document.

When calling the procedure, specify the full path and filename of the Word document.

For example: `SetNameAndItem "C:\Temp\Doc1.docx"`

```
Public Sub SetNameAndItem(strPath As String)
    Dim wdApp As Object: Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Dim wdDoc As Object: Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(strPath, False, True, False)
    Dim objRegEx As Object: Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    Dim objMatches As Object

    On Error GoTo ProcError

    With objRegEx
        .Global = False
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = "^Name:\s(.*?)$"
    End With

    Set objMatches = objRegEx.Execute(wdDoc.Content)
    If objMatches.Count = 0 Then
        Debug.Print "Name: No match."
    Else
        Range("A1").Value = objMatches(0).SubMatches(0)
    End If

    objRegEx.Pattern = "^Item:\s(.*?)\smaterial"
    Set objMatches = objRegEx.Execute(wdDoc.Content)
    If objMatches.Count = 0 Then
        Debug.Print "Item: No match."
    Else
        Range("A2").Value = objMatches(0).SubMatches(0)
    End If

ProcExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    wdDoc.Close False
    wdApp.Quit
    Set objMatches = Nothing
    Set objRegEx = Nothing
    Set wdDoc = Nothing
    Set wdApp = Nothing
    Exit Sub
ProcError:
  MsgBox "Error# " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description, , "SetNameAndItem"
  Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```

Result:

[image]

Note: Please ensure that the line breaks in your Word document consist of the normal Carriage Return / Line Feed character combination (the results of pressing pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key). When I copied/pasted the text from your Question, the document looked as expected, but what appeared to be line feeds were actually Vertical Tab characters, so the Regular Expressions did not work. I'm not saying there was any error on your part, it's probably an artifact of pasting text the web page. Just something to be aware of.

UPDATE:

If the Regular Expressions in the above code don't work, then perhaps it was not a copy/paste issue after all, and you really do have Vertical Tab characters in your document. If that's the case, try modifying the `SetNameAndItem` procedure in the Excel VBA code as follows.

Replace these two lines (which use `^` and `$` to represent start and end of line, respectively):

```
.Pattern = "^Name:\s(.*?)$"

objRegEx.Pattern = "^Item:\s(.*?)\smaterial"
```

With these two lines (which use `\v` to represent vertical tab):

```
.Pattern = "\vName:\s(.*?)\v"

objRegEx.Pattern = "\vItem:\s(.*?)\smaterial"
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I've marked the question as answered, because it indeed works completely fine. However, not for me...... The documents I work with do not have the normal Carriage Return / Line Feed character combination. Does that mean this code is useless for me or can I make it work by adjusting some things?

Comment: With my example it indeed works, but with my documents it didn't. So i did some research and it appeared that I needed to use \n instead of \v. Tried it and it worked!!! Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution of your problem:

1. Use this function to read the word file:

   ```
   Option Explicit

   Public Function f_my_story() as string

       Dim wdApp       As Object
       Dim wdDoc       As Object

       Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

       With wdApp

           .Visible = True
           Set wdDoc = .Documents.Open("C:\Users\v\Desktop\text.docx", False, True, False)
           f_my_story = wdDoc.Range(0, wdDoc.Range.End)
           wdDoc.Close False
           .Quit

       End With

   End Function
   ```
2. Once you have read the file, you get a string. Now you need a macro, which separates the string by space and it returns the values, that are after the values you are looking for.
3. You can write those values anywhere you want.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help already. But I'm a beginning programmer in VBA and i don't have any idea where to start with point 2. Where should I look for on the internet??

Comment: Here for example - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25299074/how-to-split-string-and-delimiters-into-an-array